# Trouble with loops in a program to find prime numbers

Tags: c#, loops, console-application, nested-loops

Hi I have been having a problem working out how to get this to work. It's 
intended to find the first x number of prime numbers using a user input to set x. It will then place any in an array before printing the results. I think I have made an issue with the loops as once the user input is entered nothing will happen. I'd be grateful if anyone could maybe point out where I have gone wrong and provide suggestions on how to fix it. Thanks

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int max, i, count;
        i = 0; // this is used to keep trck of how many primes have been added to the array
        count = 0; // this is used to test each number
        Console.WriteLine("This will work out the first x prime numbers with x being the number of prime numbers you want");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of prime numbers you want.");
        max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] primes = new int[max];

        while (i <= max)
        {
         while (count <= 9999)
         {
             if (count % 2 == 0 || count % 3 == 0 || count % 5 == 0 || count % 7 == 0 ) // tests if count number is a prime 
             {
                 if (count == 2 || count == 3 ||count == 5 ||count == 7 ) // ensures 2,3,5,7 are added to primes if neccesarry
                 {

                     primes[count] = count; //add to array
                     i++; // increments the count on the number of prime numbers
                 }
                 count ++; // increments the count 
                 break;
             }
             else
             {
                 primes[count] = count;
                 i++;
                 count ++;
             }
         }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The first {0} prime numbers are ... ", max);
        foreach(var item in primes)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ToString() + ", ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Work out what will happen when you test 121 (=11*11). It 's not divisible by 2,3,5 or 7...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of trying to keep to your original code, here is an adjusted take on your algorithm, modified to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://statsfiddle.info/Primes/SieveOfEratosthenes):

- The Sieve can iteratively determine all primes, with only the knowledge that 2 is a prime.
- The exit condition on the inner loop should be when the we exceed the square root of the number we are testing, with our list of known primes (not `9999` and `break`). Because of the definition of a prime number, with a list of prime numbers up to X, we can resolve all other prime numbers up to X * X. (So we can stop testing if we exceed the square root e.g. 2 can resolve 3 and 4, 2 and 3 can resolve up to 9, etc). This is also because our primes are already ordered in ascending order.
- I've kept the original variables, i.e. `count` is the next tested candidate prime, `i` is the current index of the prime, `max` is upper bound to populate.
- The first prime, 2, needs to be hard coded (i.e. `primes[0] = 2`, the next prime index `i` will be 1, and the first candidate number we need to check thereafter will be 3.

```
// We do need to hard code that 2 is a prime number. Everything else can be derived
primes[0] = 2;
i = 1;
count = 3;

// i.e. stop when we get the required number of primes
while (i < max)
{
    // Indicator to stop testing this candidate if we find a factor
    bool foundFactor = false;
    // Start off each primality test from the start of our primes array
    var primeIndex = 0;

    // Try and find a factor of 'count' with our known primes
    while (!foundFactor && primeIndex < i)
    {
        // We can stop after the square root. Multiplication is faster than sqrt
        if (primes[primeIndex]*primes[primeIndex] > count)
            break;
        // If the candidate number
        if (count % primes[primeIndex] == 0)
            foundFactor = true;
        primeIndex++;
    }
    if (!foundFactor)
    {
        primes[i] = count;
        i++;
    }

    count++;
}
```

As per @Massimo's link, the above brute force mechanism is terribly inefficient. An improvement is the 'wheel of 6' referenced in the Wiki article - after `count=6`, the wheel of 6 takes each candidate set of numbers to test in batches of 6, and all multiples of 2 and 3 can immediately be eliminated. Other larger wheels are also possible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's not the way to test if a number is a prime number, but then again, the cycle is all wrong.

If you put a max which is higher that the number of prime numbers less than 9999 it will cycle in the outer loop forever.

Check the wiki for some first insights: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

To check my statement you could add some console output in the outer loop and see for yourself